# Is there a reason to use multiple question marks instead of an asterisk in filename expansion?

Tags: wildcards

If I have a number of directories, named, for example `10001` through `10025` is there any reason to use `ls 1*/foo` vs. `ls 100??/foo`?

I have a lot more than 25 of them, so I mostly curious if there's any differences in speed.

I know the difference in use between the two, that the asterisk will match longer file names, like `10001.backup`. But let's say I don't have any files that don't follow my conventions. Is there any behind-the-scenes differences?

Comment: It isn't a speed issue. It is a specificity issue. Many times one thinks an aggressive Regex will do but one gets bitten by a corner case one didn't think about. e.g. One wants to delete dirs 10001 through 10025 only to realize there was an unrelated dir called 1world_data that became an unintended casualty. Ergo, I think its good practice to glob only the closest match. It's the safe way in the long run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Function

They mean different things. The [asterisk](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#ASTERISKREF) matches zero to infinity characters. The [question mark](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#WILDCARDQU) matches exactly one character.

From the references above:

> The * character serves as a "wild card" for filename expansion in globbing.
>
> The ? character serves as a single-character "wild card" for filename expansion in globbing…

## Performance

**tl;dr: there is no detectable difference in performance.**

I tested performance by using a directory filled with 36 sub-directories, each named with a single character. There were about 70 000 files in the subdirectories combined. I tested the following.

```
$ time ls ?/* -d >/dev/null
$ time ls */* -d >/dev/null
```

I alternated each command ten times each. Here are the results for the `real` time, in seconds.

```
?       *
0.318   0.326
0.355   0.212
0.291   0.351
0.291   0.265
0.287   0.283
0.362   0.23
0.248   0.33
0.286   0.283
0.293   0.351
0.233   0.352
```

After statistical analysis (paired t-test, two-tailed), I could detect no difference between the two values in performance (p value = 0.95).

[image: Graph]

### EDIT: More samples

I repeated the above analysis with 200 samples each, again alternating tests.

```
$ for i in {1..200}; do time (ls */* -d >/dev/null) 2>> /tmp/time_asterisk; time (ls ?/* -d >/dev/null) 2>> /tmp/time_question_mark; done
```

Here are the raw data for [?](http://pastebin.com/8nvuFfW4) and [*](http://pastebin.com/1qUBbv4U). Again, I could detect no significant difference (p value = 0.55), and the distribution of each test looks more similar.

[image: graph2]

Comment: You can compare results faster, and on larger sample with the loop: `time ( for i in {1..1000}; do ls ?/* -d >/dev/null; done )`. However I would be surprised if there would be some significant differences, and even if - they would be shell-dependent.

Comment: @jimmij Yes, I might try that later.

Comment: @jimmij Okay done. I was impatient, so I "only" did 200 samples, but it looks pretty convincing to me. I also alternated tests instead of running each consecutively, to minimise systemic effects.

Comment: *"There were about 70 000 files in the subdirectories combined."* - Just curious, is this a significant parameter in your testing? Did you test with just a file, or no nested files? :)

Comment: @h.j.k. To be honest, I just used a convenient directory I had, which was a complete clone of the old Arch Linux AUR, sorted into directories based on the first letter. If I were creating the test from scratch, I'd probably create directories named 0001–9999 instead, as I think iterating *over* the wildcard would be more relevant. However, in this case, I think I did enough replicates overall that any differences should be apparent.

Comment: @Sparhawk ah I sees, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

The `??` are more specific, in the event there are or could be other, longer files the `*` glob would match.

```
% touch 10001 100dalmations
% ls 100??
10001
% ls 100*
10001  100dalmations
%
```

Comment: I realize that, but is there any difference when there are no longer-named files?

Comment: No; both run through the same shell glob code path where I'd wager disk I/O dominates regardless the glob expression.