# What does the ls ????? command do?

Tags: ls

I was trying to learn more about Linux and came across the command ls ????? and it displayed a few files in the directory but I am not really sure what it is specifically displaying. I tried to use the man to explain it further but I couldn't find anything. Could someone please explain?

Comment: Try `man 7 glob`. Also [Is there a reason to use multiple question marks instead of an asterisk in filename expansion?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223814/is-there-a-reason-to-use-multiple-question-marks-instead-of-an-asterisk-in-filen)

Comment: @steeldriver I'm not sure, it was just a command I came across while trying to learn sys ad functions and it didn't make sense to me when I tried it. Edit: It looks like I specifically look for files/directories with 5 characters

Comment: @JeffSchaller, saying it's a dup of that other Q&A is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'd be happy to reopen it, but I understand this question as "I looked at `man ls` but don't understand what `ls ?????` is doing", and the other Q/A explains what the question-mark matches. I would love a better source-duplicate.

Comment: Perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/413357/117549 ?

Comment: The ? character serves as a single-character "wild card" for filename expansion in globbing. It matches exactly one character.

Answer (score -4):

ls is a command on its own - try man ls for an explanation.
ls ? may give a help summary in some Linux versions.
ls with multiple ? is pointless as far as I know unless all the files listed have just five characters?.

Comment: I found that the ls ????? will display files/directories with names of 5 characters. If I wanted to search for a file that I know started with R and was 5 characters but didn't remember the name I would us ls R???? and that would give me everything in that directory matching those requirements.

Comment: This question has very little to do with `ls` and much more to do with the question-marks... in fact, using a varying number of question marks demonstrates the point.

Comment: It looks like it is matching for patterns, normally ls R* would give you any filenames of any length and R???? will do what you say.  Perhaps look at man grep for more details on pattern matching.

Comment: `ls /?` would give a help summary... in DOS and Windows. (Except that the command there is called `dir`) I don't think I've ever seen `/?` or `-?` or such as giving a help text in any unix programs. `?` by itself is a valid filename pattern (glob) for a one-letter filename, which you pretty much already know based on that last sentence. `grep` uses regular expressions, they're not the same as glob patterns. See here for the latter: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns